# sdef command not found - OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to follow the instructions here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-SW1

Whenever I try to use the "sdef" command I'm getting a "command not found" error. This worked fine under 10.7. I'm trying to use it under 10.8 and it doesn't work anymore.

Was the sdef command removed in 10.8? What should I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `xcrun sdef`; that'll use the copy of `sdef` inside the Xcode application bundle.  Most developer tools have been moved into the bundle in recent Xcode versions.  You can also try installing the command-line tools from inside Xcode's preferences.